# Modern keyboard virtuosi?

Tags: piano

I am amused by the story of Beethoven dueling another composer in Vienna, in which he takes the other composer's music, puts it upside down, and proceeds to humiliate him. I feel as though keyboardists with that kind of talent must exist nowadays, but they are perhaps not as popular as they once were.

Do we have such "Rockstar" pianists in the modern age? Who are they?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it invites an open-ended list of answers.

Comment: @Aaron maybe it belongs on musicfans?  Also, it's old.  I wonder why it wasn't closed long ago!

Comment: @Theodore My understanding is that the site's conventions around close reasons have evolved over time. This may not have raised any eyebrows wen it was first asked. I only noticed it when it showed up in the Close Votes queue (as "needs details/clarify"). I agree with you that Music Fans is really the better site, but the "open-ended list" issue would still be a problem. One of the core SE "rules" is that questions should have clear, discrete(ish) answers. That gets stretched here by necessity, but this one is obviously open-ended.

Answer (score 2):

The type of keyboard music typically composed during the classical age was so much less complex, and the number of professional musicians was so much smaller, that the comparison cannot be made in any reasonable way.

A lot of present-day pianists could probably sight-read the music of a second-rate composer from 1800. But that was a time when the music of Liszt, Alkan, Ligeti, Messiaen etc. etc. did not exist, and would have been considered absurd and obviously unplayable. It is impossible to say whether there are living musicians who are as phenomenal by current standards as Beethoven was by *his era's* standards.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that the Beethoven "duel" is legend. By legend I don't mean that it didn't happen, only that it's one of those famous stories passed down through the generations, and stories like that only come along once or twice in a lifetime.

We certainly still have "rock star" pianists today that you might want to check out:

- [Lang Lang](https://youtu.be/jYO9gTmCJTE?t=7m46s)
- [Denis Matsuev](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_tdBFx37Mps)
- [Yuja Wang](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8alxBofd_eQ)
- And one example from an earlier era: [Sviatoslav Richter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GQ-NAgDpRVs)

And there's something to be said about someone that uses their encore to play [that piece that all the six year olds learn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xTVF8e5pbNY).

Comment: And then there's Josef Zawinul, who used an inverted keyboard with high notes to the left and low notes to the right  just to keep him thinking.

Answer (score 2):

One of my favorite up-and-coming pianist/composers is Aysedeniz Gokcin.  Not yet 30 years old, she's someone who combines a marvelous piano technique with impressive compositional skills.

Here's her "Pink Floyd Lisztified," an arrangement of some of Pink Floyd's songs in the manner of Liszt:

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely check out keyboardists from progressive rock bands. Prog rock musicians really introduced synthesizers to the popular music/rock scene and elicited really unconventional sounds from those synthesizers. Listen to what they'd done with synthesizers in the 70s, and you'd be amazed. That was 50 years ago!

The most famous keyboard giants of prog rock are probably Keith Emerson of the band Emerson, Lake and Palmer, known for his flamboyant live performances and unconventional techniques (e.g. sticking a knife into a keyboard), and Rick Wakeman of the band Yes, who was much less flamboyant but nevertheless a great keyboardist who created many interesting sounds.

My favorite, however, is Rick Wright of the venerable Pink Floyd; he wasn't into doing crazy, virtuosic things with his keyboards, but he was really good at creating sounds and conveying moods and atmospheres with his synths.

Answer (score 0):

[Jordan Rudess](http://www.jordanrudess.com/) (Dream Theater) is an impressive keyboarder and a true wizard, maybe not quite as famous as Beethoven. He's not only an accomplished piano virtuoso, he's also constantly pushing the boundaries of his instrument, e.g. by controlling and designing sounds in innovative ways such as with the Haken Continuum and his iPad apps.